# Python/Nose/Testing Why does pickling a OrderedDict fail?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, nose, nosetests

I´ve come about some very strange behavior in one of my nose tests for GAE, not quite sure on how to debug it further... Any idea why it fails would be appreciated...

```
# Main Testing file stripped to the basics
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import unittest
import pickle

from collections import OrderedDict
from ptest import SomeClass


class PickleTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def runTest(self):
        res = OrderedDict()

        for item in [1, 2, 3]:
            res[item] = "test"

        #works
        pickle.dumps(res)

        #fails
        otherClass = SomeClass()
        test = otherClass.pTest("Nav")

if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()
```

The imported class file:

```
import pickle

from collections import OrderedDict

class SomeClass:
    def pTest(self, tableName=None, rightsTrimmed=True):
        return pickle.dumps(OrderedDict())
```

leads to

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'collections.OrderedDict'>: it's not the same object as collections.OrderedDict
```

But strangely enough only for the statement in the imported class, not the main one.

I´m at the end of my wisdom. Being executed in the normal GAE dev/production environment, the code works... The system Python version is Python 2.7.5.

Comment: try adding '--pdb' and unroll the failure further. Sometimes nose will try to be helpful and modify the loading path for modules, resulting in a wrong modules being imported, like http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201311/adhoc_data_breakpoints.html

Comment: I´ll call a exorcist... As soon as I insert a breakpoint into the code and then upon execution press c(ontinue) the test passes without error. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9We2XsVZfc

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Oleksiy, I´ve figured out that when inserting a breakpoint, the test ran though without modifying the code. Stange. I can´t really imagine why, but this has given me the idea that something really strange in terms of timing is going on. And, to confirm that suspicion, I´ve tried a late import of the OrderedDict, which works.

It´s a first find, changing my production code to late imports to allow tests to run seems crazy. I´ll read up on late imports and think about on how to proceed...

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pickle

#from collections import OrderedDict

class SomeClass:
    def pTest(self, tableName=None, rightTrimmed=True):
        # The Demons seem to be pleased by the late import...
        from collections import OrderedDict
        return pickle.dumps(OrderedDict())
```

Comment: check the path to see if you are importing from the same collections before the test and after the test.

Comment: Both cases import the same "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/collections.py". It´s also the same for the main file and the troubled one...